# How to make K-S two sample test for distance?

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test

Newbie in stats here and I would like a bit of help.

I have geographical data consisted of many points (locations) and one vector line between them (river). I would like to do a Kolmogorov Smirnov two sample test to see how many of the geographical points are within 200 meters of the river. How could I do this and with what software? I would like to present the results in a graph with X (distance) and Y axis.

Comment: I think you need to edit your post to give us more explanation. As it stands the answer to your question seems to be "Just count them" so it is hard to see where the need for K-S comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kolmogorov Smirnov  two sample test is done to test if two samples are taken from the same distribution. In your problem, the samples are : (1) first sample consists of the location of all geographical data you already have (2) you would need to generate a second sample (from the river vector) of the locations which are at a distance of 200 meters of the river. If the two samples follow the same distribution, then your geographical points are within the given distance. So you plot the cumulative distribution of each sample to check if they are taken from the same distribution. That will give you the X-Y plot you are looking for, where X is the distance and y is the cumulative distribution. You can have a look at the second illustration at the wiki page to interpret your figure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test

To caluculate the statistic (maximum deviation between the two distribution) and the corresponding p-value, you can easily use python implementation of KS 2 sampel test given here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html

An example is also given at the end of the python page. Basically just feed in the values of the two samples described above and then check the statistic and p-value.

I don't think that you need KS test to calculate the number of  geographical data.